# GetKeyDown doesn't seem to be working. Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Making a little prototype at work and have been following some tutorials on how to do UI. Everything seems to be working except for the fact that hitting "space" while playing doesn't pause the game. I added some debug logs to try and catch where it was breaking, but I get no log output when hitting the space key. Which I think means something is breaking before or at the point where it should be looking for GetKeyDown.

In editor I have the Resume button and "Paused" text all set with the tag "ShowOnPause". If I comment out the hidePaused in the start function they appear correctly so I don't think it's a error in the editor.

If anyone sees anything else I could be doing better please share. Still trying to learn this stuff.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
// Array of gameObjects for the Pause Menu
GameObject[] pauseObjects;

void Start () 
{
    //Game is running at start
    Time.timeScale = 1;
    // Assign all objects with the ShowOnPause to pauseObjects
    pauseObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ShowOnPause");            
    //Hide all pause UI at start
    hidePaused();
    Debug.Log("UI Hidden");

}

void Update () 
{
    // If the space key is pressed 
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Debug.Log("Key Pressed");   

        // and if the game is running
        if(Time.timeScale == 1)
        {
            // Pause the game and show Pause Menu
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            showPaused();
            Debug.Log("Paused");
        } 
        // or if the game is already paused
        else if (Time.timeScale == 0)
        {
            // Resume the game and hide the Pause Menu
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            hidePaused();
            Debug.Log("UnPaused");
        }
    }
}

// The function for activating gameobjects in the Pause Menu array
public void showPaused()
{
    foreach(GameObject g in pauseObjects)
    {
        g.SetActive(true);
        Debug.Log("Showing UI");
    }
}

// The Function for deactivating the gameobjects in the Pause Menu array
public void hidePaused()
{
    foreach(GameObject g in pauseObjects)
    {
        g.SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log("Hiding UI");
    }
}

// Function for the Resume button in the Pause Menu
public void Resume()
{
    if(Time.timeScale == 1)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        showPaused();
    } 
    else if (Time.timeScale == 0)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        hidePaused();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The brace is not correctly placed : `if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        Debug.Log("Key Pressed");   
    {`. Should be before the `Debug.Log`

Comment: Thanks. Fixed that and edited post. Original problem was not fixed however

Comment: Does a simple `Debug.Log("Update is called")` in the Update, outside the condition, is called?
Is the object holding the `UIManager` script in the `pauseObjects` list? If so, it is disabled in the `Start` function, explaining why `Update` is not running.

Comment: I would debug.log the name of every gameobject turned off in "hidePaused".. Make sure you aren't turning off the gameobject that UIManager resides on.

Comment: You do know you are doing an == check on a floating point value?  Try doing a check with a tolerance like `if(Time.timeScale - 1 <= Mathf.Epsilon)`

Comment: Another test would be to use `Mathf.Approximately`

Comment: That was it. Had the UIManager attached to a object that was being disabled in the Start function. Made a prefab for the UIManager and ended up dropping that in in the Canvas but didn't set it to ShowOnPause. Also the mathf.Epsilon/Approximately is new to me so I'll look that up in the documentation. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
```